# Склонение имён среднего рода

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

В советском фильме про Садко 1953 года купцы склоняют его имя. Почему? Единственное, что могу предположить, так то, что это ради издёвки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фильм-сказка "Садко" был снят в СССР в 1952 году режиссером Александром Птушко.
Вот какая информация имеется в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE):

> В оригинальных текстах имя Садко склоняется по парадигме, свойственной в северорусском наречии всем словам с суффиксом *-ко*:
> Им. падеж — Садко́
> Род. падеж — Садка́
> Дат. падеж — Садку́
> Вин. падеж — Садка́
> Твор. падеж — Садко́м
> Предл. падеж — о Садке́
> <...>
> В советской практике возобладало употребление имени Садко в неизменяемом виде (как и для имеющих суффикс *-ко* украинских фамилий).

Вот как говорил известный российский лингвист Ф. И. Буслаев ([**речь**](http://az.lib.ru/b/buslaew_f_i/text_1859_o_narodnoy_poezii.shtml), произнесенная в торжественном собрании Московского университета 12 января 1859 года, "О народной поэзии в древнерусской литературе"):
*Подымалась тогда погода тихая, понесло **Садка** по волнам и причалило к берегу, где он встретил Морского царя, или самого бога вод.*

Вот как писал граф А. К. Толстой (["Садко"](http://www.gotorn.ru/f_poetry_rus/t/tolstoy_ak_sadko.html), 1872):
*50

Степенный посадник, и тысяцкий тут,

И старых посадников двое,

И с ними кончанские старосты пьют

Здоровье **Садку** круговое.*

Так что, думаю, в склонении имени Садко нет никакой издевки, а есть дань древнерусской литературе и одной из ветвей языка, а также, возможно, и то, что "советской практике" было всего-то тридцать лет.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Нет, про издёвку мне и в голову не приходило!)

Comment: И Вас, Артём, благодарю за оценку ответа. P. S. А словечко-то я использовала Ваше (оно есть в вопросе). P. P. S. Я задала вопрос на "Мете" (со ссылкой на Ваш) — о знаке "Возрождение". Хотелось бы знать Ваше мнение.

Comment: Ой, и правда, писал про издёвку.))) Странно тогда мысль повернулась. Но вообще, я вроде сразу подумал, что раз склоняют, то так было принято. А предположение насчёт издёвки, видимо, заведомо неверное, потому что здравых предположений и вовсе не было других. А может, мы всё-таки друг другу будем писать "вы" с маленькой для простоты?)